# What should the height of a cylinder of radius $5$ be to optimize its volume?

Tags: calculus

> What should the height of a cylinder be, in order to optimize its volume. Keep in mind the cylinder has a radius of 5 cm.

Comment: What have you tried. I'm not sure what you mean by optimize. Please read our [guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: The height could be arbitrarily large.

Comment: Or just $0$. The question doesn’t seem to be complete.

Comment: By "optimize", do you mean "maximize"? In which case, it can be arbitrarily large. Or perhaps you mean to maximise its volume - surface area ratio?

Comment: The question seems to be incomplete. Usually an optimisation problem includes some constraint - for example, a maximum surface area for the cylinder.

Answer (score 2):

A formula for the volume of a cylinder depending on its height is

$$V(h) = h\cdot A$$

where $A$ is the area of its base. This area is given by $A = r^2\cdot \pi$. Now unless any other conditions are placed on the cylinder then by letting $h$ get bigger the volume grows and therefore there is no maximum volume. Minimum would occur when $h=0$ but then it is hardly a cylinder...